# Can you help me convert this route to rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I read a few websites and questions but all were far beyond my level except one site:

http://markconnell.co.uk/posts/2010/02/rails-3-routing-examples

I'm trying to follow Head First Rails which was made for Rails 2 and so far it's been going well enough. I've been able to find the conversions so far, this is really the first place since installation to stump me.

It says in the config/routes.rb file that it should read:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect '/ads/:id', :controller=>'ads', :action=>'show'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

First off my routes.rb file defaults that first line to be

```
Mebay::Application.routes.draw do
```

So my first attempt read:

```
Mebay::Application.routes.draw do
  map.connect '/ads/:id', :controller=>'ads', :action=>'show'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

When that failed I tried this:

```
Mebay::Application.routes.draw do'
map '/ads/:id' => 'ads#index'
end
```

Then I tried the same thing but adding |map| to the first line.

And finally, I tried changing it all to this:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
map '/ads/:id' => 'ads#index'
end
```

None of these have worked though. Could someone please help me out here, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have another book, Ruby On Rails 3 by Hartl but in the Index it doesn't even show anything on Routes so don't even know where to look in there.

Thanks for any help you can offer me!

**// EDIT -** I also tried with it reading '/ads/':id thinking perhaps that is a mistake since it doesn't make sense to me why :id would be inside quotes.

**// EDIT 2 -** This is what Rake Routes returns:

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at /Users/Dennis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods
WARNING: DSL method Mebay::Application#task called at /Users/Dennis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
/ads/:id(.:format)                 {:controller=>"ads", :action=>"show"}
/:controller/:action/:id(.:format) 
/:controller/:action/:id.:format
```

Error Message:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/ads/3"

**//EDIT 3 -** This is what my 2 controller files look like:

ads_controller:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
end
```

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery
end
```

**//EDIT 4 -**

Tried in the ads_controller.rb file:
    class AdsController < ApplicationController
      def show;
      end
    end

Also tried in the same file:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
end
def show;
end
```

And each way I tried going to

- localhost:3000/mebay/ads/3
- localhost:3000/ads/3
- localhost:3000/show/ads/3
- localhost:3000/mebay/show/ads/3

Same error still "Routing Error. No Route Matches..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do 
  match '/ads/:id' => 'ads#show'
  match ':controller/:action/:id'
  match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

I thoroughly recommend reading the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing

Comment: Wow, I missed that Map needed to be switched to Match on the Mark Connel website. That was just carelessness. Thanks and I'm reading that article now!

Comment: hmm I just got home from work and tried that; it didn't work. Perhaps I'm not pointing at the right page. I tried: localhost:3000/ads/3/ and then thought maybe it needs to be localhost:3000/mebay/ads/3/ but neither one worked. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: This kind of depends on what is your controller name. The above syntax is a shortcut really, you could try something like `match 'ads/:id', :controller => AdsController, :action => "show"` where `AdsController` would be whatever your controller's name is. Also what error are you getting? A helpful trick is also to run `rake routes` to list all the routes that are recognized.

Comment: I just ran "Rake Routes" and edited my question to include its output which I don't particularly understand yet. I also put in the Error message that I'm getting. It has been this error message for all the different attempts.

Comment: That's pretty weird. I would think that should work. Can you perhaps post your controller (and it's file path)? Also does `localhost:3000/ads/show/3' work?

Comment: Tried localhost:3000/ads/show/3 and got the same results. I have 2 different Controllers now one called ads_controller.rb and another called application_controller.rb, both are in I believe C:/mebay/app/controllers/ directory the directory bar shows: Macintosh HD > Users > Dennis > mebay > app > controllers >

I edited my question with post controller files since I'm not sure which you want to see.

Comment: OK, well you don't seem to have an action in your controller. Try adding `def show; end` in to the AdsController class. This should give you an no template found error instead of a routing error. Can you check that that is so?

Answer (score 2):

I also am using that book and going through for a difference between rails 2 and rails 3.

I got this to work. In routes.rb file all you need to do is add this between the do and the end:

```
resources :ads
```

The key is that your routes.rb file is only sending that resource to the right spot. The next place to look is the ads_controller.rb file where you will want to add this:

```
 #Get /ads/1
 #Get /ads/1.json

  def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ad }
    end
  end
```

The next part is adding the index which is a bit later in that chapter. You'll want to add this above that:

```
# GET /ads
# GET /ads.json
 def index
  @ads = Ad.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @ad }
        end
      end
```

Basically if you look at the chapter 1 routes.rb and controller files you'll see that scaffold configures a rails 3 app like that. One more thing that confused me was I was only able to get the javascript to work by putting it in /app/assets/stylesheets and editing application.html.erb and setting the stylesheet link to look like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "default.css" %>
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 3 you don't want to do a Rails 2 tutorial. There are plenty of good rails 3 tutorials out there. For your question about routes, see the blog post below which might help you figure it out.

http://gregmoreno.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/rails-3-upgrade-part-2-routes/

Comment: I saw that, I didn't understand it. And as for books - this is the easiest one on the market. Hartl's book lost me after Chapter 2, I got stuck on the Tests so tried skipping them like he recommended but then got stuck on the chapter after that as a result. If there was a Head First Rails for 3.0 I'd get it. :\ Do you have an alternative suggestion of a tutorial for someone with no backend experience, no ide experience, nothing. All I've ever done is HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: a really good book is 'agile web development with rails', its only $20ish and a really good starting point for a newbie. http://pragprog.com/book/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails

Comment: I asked on here I guess two weeks ago considering getting that and was told it is more advanced than either of the books I have and they suggested I either stick with Head First or regress to Programming With Ruby by Pine before even starting with Rails.

Comment: Nah it starts with some basic stuff, the standard 'Hello World' example and some basic Ruby code. I highly recommend it. It walks you through a nice generic online store example.

Answer (score 1):

Try making this your Routes file. I had the same problem while doing it from Chapter 2 of Head First Rails. But this resolved it for me

```
    Mebay::Application.routes.draw do

       controller 'ads' do
               match 'ads/:id' => :show
       end

    end
```